# PHP SpeedTester

Tags: php

Возможно ли средствами PHP измерить скорость закачки? Желательно в кб/с. Если да, то хотел бы понять принцип работы.

Answer (score 4):

Принцип предельно простой, и неважно какими именно средствами это делается:

1. Запоминаем текущее время (`start`)
2. Получаем файл
3. Запоминаем текущее время (`stop`)
4. Скорость закачки = `размер_файла / (stop - start)`

Для отметок времени в PHP можно использовать функцию [microtime(true)](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php).

P.S. Понятно, что чем меньше файл и чем меньше измерений, тем больше будет погрешность.